Finding a solution with few near-zeros
I would like to find a solution to $Ax=b$ with some goals for $x$ that I'm having a hard time describing mathematically. In a hand-wavy way, I would like $x$ to be as close to uniform (meaning $x_i = x_j \forall i, j$) as possible. I also need $x_i \ge 0 \forall i$.
I have tried encoding this as the QP
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 \min_x && || x - [1/n]_n||^2 \\
s.t. && Ax = b \\
&& x \ge 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
hoping that this would yield a solution that is close (in L2) to the completely uniform vector $[1/n]^n$ (where $n$ is the dimensionality of $x$). I used CVXOPT to solve this with $A$ of size 6x100 (values randomly drawn between 0 and 1) and $b = [1/6]_6$. The result was an $x^*$ with 90% near zero values ($x_i < 1e-5$) and a few larger values. This doesn't meet my goal of having "near uniform" values in $x$.
I know the issue is with my encoding of my goal into an optimization function. Clearly, $Ax=b$ can be solved with an $x$ that has 94 zeros and 6 nonzeros. So I need some smarter way to translate my goal into an equation.
I tried bumping up my constraint $x \ge 0$ to $x \ge 0.1, 0.2, 0.3$ etc. and this did what I asked it to do (no values below the 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.), but there were still very few $x_i$ with much larger values. That spikiness is the very thing I'm trying to avoid.
Still grasping at how to encode my definition of "spikiness", it feels like I want to minimize $\max_{i,j} (x_i - x_j)^2$ or something like that, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.
The context might be helpful: I'm looking to find optimal sample weights for a machine learning dataset. Using the above numbers, I have 100 data points (in practice much larger) with 6 constraints on how I want my data to be balanced. A very "spiky" weighting vector is bad from a ML perspective, because my learning algorithm will get almost all of its information from very few data points. This is unlikely to generalize well to non-training data. Better, from a ML point of view, is to change the weighting (away from uniform) as little as possible. Meaning, the ML algorithm still gets information from the whole dataset, but a few instances have slightly higher weight than others.

Maybe try minimizing $\sum_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)^2$.

Thanks @RobPratt, I like that idea a lot but I'm not sure how to do it. I guess the full program would be $\min \sum_{i,j} (x_i - x_j)^2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad Ax=b, x \ge 0$. Does that fit the form of a standard QP? Doesn't seem like it to me, but I've been surprised before.

Yes, it is a quadratic objective function and linear constraints.

Sorry if I'm being dense, but can you show me how to put it in the form $\min x^\top Q x + c^\top x$? That's the interface that CVXOPT offers, and I don't see what $Q$ and $c$ would yield $\sum_{i,j}(x_i - x_j)^2$.

Hint: write $(x_i-x_j)^2=x_i^2+x_j^2-2x_ix_j$.  Also, $c=0$.

I appreciate the hint. I think I'm close but probably not quite there yet. Something like $Q = (N+1) * I_{N \times N} - 2 * 1_{N \times N}$ ? I'm envisioning a matrix with $N-1$ along the diagonal and $-2$ everywhere else. Does that sound right?

Yes, that is close. See the answer I just added.

Try minimizing
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i^2+x_j^2-2x_i x_j) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(n x_i^2 +\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-2x_i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right) \\
&= n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +n \sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j\\
&= 2n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j\\
\end{align}

Thanks. Looks like this can be written as $x^\top Q x$ with $Q = 2n*I_{n \times n} - 2 * 1_{n \times n}$. I'll try this and report back.

works much better than what I was trying, thank you for the help!
